# Compare $\ln(\pi)$ and $\pi-2$ without calculator

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, approximation

Unlike the famous question of comparing $e^\pi$ and $\pi^e$, which I solved almost instantly, I am stuck with this problem.  My thought was the following.

Since exponential function is order-preserving, we exponentiate both terms and get $\pi$ and $e^{\pi-2}$.  Then we study the function $f(x) = e^{x-2} - x$ or the function $g(x) = \frac{e^{x-2}}{x}$, and compare them with zero and one respectively.  I tried both.  But both involve solving the equation
$$e^{x-2} = x.$$

I tried Lagrange error terms and have
$$f(x) = -1 + \frac{(x-2)^2}{2!} + R_2(x-2),$$
where
$$\frac{(x-2)^3}{3!} \le R_2(x-2) \le \frac{e^{x-2}}{3!} (x-2)^3.$$

It is easy to see that the equation have a root between $3$ and $2 + \sqrt2$.  But I don't know how close it is to $\pi$.  It is to provide some lower bounds since we can plug in some values and calculate to show that $f(x) > 0$ for such values.  But for the upper bound, it is hard to calculate by hands since it has the $e^{x-2}$ factor.  At my best attempt by hand, I showed that $f(3.15) > 0$.  All it entails is that for all $x \ge 3.15$, $e^{x-2}$ is greater than $x$.  But it tells nothing about the other side.

Then I looked at the calculator and find that $e^{\pi-2} < \pi$.

I also tried Newton-Raphson iteration, but it involves a lot of exponentiation which is hard to calculate by hand and also involves approximation by themselves.  And I don't know how fast and close the iteration converges to the true root of the equation.

Any other hint for comparing these two number purely by hand?

Comment: Coincidentally enough, the difference is really small, making the common approach of defining a function and root approximating very dicey

Comment: $f(x)$ is strictly incresing from $-1$ to $+\infty$ on $[2,+\infty)$. Thus, it has precisely one real root on that interval, which turns out to be slightly larger than $\pi$ (it is $x = 3.146\ldots$). Hence, $e^{\pi-2}<\pi$. So it would be enough to show that $f(3.142)<0$. You should probably expand $f(x)$ about $x=3$ and look at the Taylor series remainder.

Comment: The values are quite close , so I guess a hand-calculation will be somewhat messy.

Comment: Here is a suggestion: define the function $f(x) = \text{ln} (\pi x) - \pi x + 2$ for all $x>0$. 
Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = - \infty$ and computing first derivative one can shows $f$ attains a global maximum at some point $\alpha < 1$ where $f(\alpha)>0$, then Bolzano theorem says there is $c\in (0,1)$ with $f(c)=0$. 
Now, since $\text{ln}$ is strictly concave, $f$ is also concave. Therefore, given any $t\in (0,1)$, $0<f(t1 + (1-t)c) < t f(1) + (1-t)f(c) = t f(1)$. This leads to $f(1)>0$, which means $\text{ln}(\pi) > \pi -2.$

Comment: Exactly, the difference is like 0.00314 (quite amusing)

Comment: In fact since the digits of $\pi$ appear again :)

Comment: @Senna, I followed your argument until the point where you claimed $$f(t1 + (1-t)c)\stackrel{?}<tf(1)+(1-t)f(c)\qquad\text{for}\qquad t\in(0,1).$$ Is this true only when $f$ is strictly convex? Also note that your argument, if works, should also work with $f(x)=\log(4x)-4x+2$ to show that $0<f(1)=\log(4)-4+2$, which is false.

Comment: Yes, I am using strictly convexity of $f$. With respect to your second question. You are right, for $log(4x) -4x +2$ the argument is not valid. The reason is because you need $f$ to be $>0$ in the interval $(c,1)$. This happens for $f$ with $\pi$ in the definition, but not with a four.

Comment: @Senna Thanks.  Is that Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @Senna I am confused about two things. First, if the function is concave, the direction of inequality should be reversed, $$f(t + (1-t)c) > tf(1) + (1-t)f(c).$$ Second, how do you know $f(x) > 0$ on $(c, 1)$. All I know is $\alpha = 1/\pi$ and there is a root on $(0, \alpha)$. $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(1/\pi, +\infty)$. We have $f(x) > 0$ on $(c, \alpha]$.

Comment: The values satisfy $\pi - 2 < \color{red}{\frac{8}{7} < \log \pi}$, and left inequality is immediately equivalent to the well-known bound $\pi < \frac{22}{7}$, so it suffices to show the right (red) inequality. It's not obvious to me how to show it elegantly.

Comment: Since $\frac{7^7}{4^9} < \pi$, it also suffices to show (after some rearranging) that $8 < 49 \log 7 - 126 \log 2$. There's a little room here, but not much (the quantity on the right-hand side is $8.01305\ldots$). I'm sure you could cook up a Dalzell-style integral to establish the inequality---i.e., an integral of a positive rational function whose (thus positive) value is $49 \log 7 - 126 \log 2 - 8$---but it might not be pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By hand I took $e^{\pi -2}<e\cdot e^{0.1416}<(2.7183)e^{0.1416}.$ Using $B_1=0.1416=0.1+0.04(1+0.04)$ for manual calculation, I computed, to $5$ decimal places, an upper bound $B_2$   for $(B_1)^2/2$ and an upper bound $B_3$ for $B_1B_2/3 $ and an upper bound $B_4$ for $B_1B_3/4,$ etc., until I was sure that the sum of the remaining terms was less than $0.00005,$ to obtain an upper bound $B$ to $4$ decimal places for $e^{0.1416}.$ Then I multiplied $B\times 2.7183$ and got less than $\pi.$

Comment: See the book The Trachtenburg Speed System Of Basic Mathematics for some wonderful ways (that I didn't even use here) to do multiplication.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. Could you kindly elaborate on "until the remaining terms was less than $0.00005$"? I believe this is where I am stuck. Is there any theorems about remainder bound I missed? How did you bound the remainder? Thanks.

Comment: Actually   $B_4$ was  as far  as I needed. In the power series for $e^x$,  the sum $S$ of the terms of degree $5$ or more in $x$ is $S=(x^5/5!)(1+x/6+x^2/6.7+x^3/6.7.8+...)$ which for $1/6>x>0$ is less than $(x^5/5!)(1+x/6+x^2/6^2+x^3/6^3+...)=(x^5/5!)/(1-x/6).$  And the sum $S$ decreases with decreasing positive $x.$ So with $x=B_1<1/7$ we have $S<((1/7)^5/5!)/(1-1/42)<10^{-5}.$

Comment: There are theorems about the remainder of a power series. If $r>0$ and if the series $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}A_jx^j$ converges whenever $|x|<r,$ then for $0<|x|<r$ and $n>0$ we have $f(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}A_jx^j= \frac {x^n f^{(n)}(y)}{n!}$ for some $y$ strictly between $0$ and $x,$ where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$th derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

All the logarithms I know by heart are
$$\begin{align}\log_{10}2&=0.30103\\
\ln10&=2.303\\
\ln2&=0.693\end{align}$$
Using the second fact alone we can solve this problem! We know that
$$\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=x+R_2(x)$$
Where
$$|R_2(x)|\le\frac{|x|^3}{3(1-|x|)^3}$$
for $|x|<1$. Then let $x=\frac{-3}{487}$ so
$$\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{22}{7\sqrt{10}}\right)=\frac{-3}{487}+R_2\left(\frac{-3}{487}\right)$$
So we have
$$\begin{align}\ln\left(\frac{22}7\right)&=\frac12\ln10-\frac3{487}+R_2\left(\frac{-3}{487}\right)\gt\frac{2.3025}2-\frac1{160}-\frac1{100^3}\\
&=1.15125-0.00625-10^{-6}=1.145-10^{-6}\gt1.143\gt\frac{22}7-2\end{align}$$
And since $f(x)=\ln x-x+2$ is decreasing for $x\gt1$ and it has been known since the
time of Archimedes that $\frac{22}7\gt\pi$ we have established the result.

But if you didn't know that $\ln10=2.303$ to $3$ decimals you might
be in for a tougher slog. You could say, for example, that
$$\ln10=10\ln\frac54+3\ln\frac{128}{125}\gt20\left(\frac19+\frac1{3\times9^3}\right)+6\left(\frac3{253}\right)$$
So that
$$\begin{align}\ln\left(\frac{22}7\right)&\gt\frac{10}9+\frac{10}{2187}+\frac9{253}-\frac3{487}-10^{-6}\\
&\gt1.1111+0.004+0.035-0.007-10^{-6}\gt1.143\\
&\gt\frac{22}7-2\end{align}$$
Where we actually had to carry out one of the long divisions to $2$ significant figures.